# Converting binary data to characters in java

Tags: java, binary, char

I have a file in which its content is only 0's and 1's

I want to write a java program that convert each 8 bit of 0's and 1's to char 
or in other word, to convert the file content from binary to chars.

Which function can I use for that purpose?

Comment: Text files are binary files containing bytes that can be interpreted as text. In other words, if these zeros and ones are arranged according to, say, ASCII, or UICODE encoding, you don't need to do anything special, just read the file in.

Comment: No, I have to write a random 0's and 1's into a text file 
Then, to read from this file and print the chars on screen

Comment: +1. In other words: all files are binary files. Some binary files happen to contain bytes that represent characters in a certain encoding.

Comment: @user1077980: so your file is a text file containing only the characters '0' and '1'?

Comment: If I wrote in text file the following: 00100001 
and I want to print on screen the content of the file in char 
for example to print "a" which function should I use?

Comment: @user1077980 You may use something like `(char)Integer.parseInt("001000001", 2)` on each group of 8 digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one is also work

```
    String s = "0110100001100101011011000110110001101111";
    String str = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length()/8; i++) {

        int a = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8*i,(i+1)*8),2);
        str += (char)(a);
    }

    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Does this work when a byte has "0000" in the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

First of al, you'll have to convert Strings of 8 '0' and '1' characters into bytes. This is easily done using [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), and converting the int to a byte using

```
byte b = (byte) (i & 0xFF)
```

Then you need to create a byte array with all these bytes.

And finally, you need to transform this byte array into a String. This is where you need to decide whcih encoding to use. The same String can be transformed into different byte arrays, depending on the encoding. And all byte sequences don't represent valid characters. Suppose you want to use ASCII as encoding, the use `new String(bytes, "ASCII")`. But beware that all bytes bigger than 128 are not valid ASCII characters.

Comment: yes, it works well :)
But how about using .hasNextByte() while reading from file 
does it work?

Comment: I tried it using : while(input.hasNextByte())  but it never enters the loop !

Comment: probably, yes, provided the radix is 2. Why don't you just test it?

Comment: while(input.hasNextByte(2)){

        System.out.println("yes");

        System.out.println(""+input.nextByte());
        
    }

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't enter the looop

Comment: It doesn't enter the loop because hasNextByte() uses Byte.parseByte(), and expects only numbers between -128 and 127, using the given radix, and a minus sign to represent negative bytes. So hasNextByte(2) will return true for 01111111 or -01111111, but false for 11111111 (thr first 1 is not interpreted as a sign bit).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the file's contents in a byte array `byte[]` you can simply use the appropriate [constructor String(byte[], Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

But be aware that some charsets use more than one byte per character, so you probably do not want to use `UTF-8` but for example `US-ASCII`.